# How to handle licensing of Ruby on Rails code, which contains a LGPL library?

Tags: licensing, ruby-on-rails, lgpl

My company wants to release the code for a Ruby on Rails demo app, which includes our own LGPL'd library code.

It it legally kosher for me to state that the contents of the entire repo are released under the LGPL, although it includes "stock" Ruby on Rails files which are generated with every app, like `boot.rb` and `application.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be entirely sure, you need to consult with a lawyer. This is a legal question that can only be answered definitively by an experienced professional in this field.

I don't know if those "stock" Ruby on Rails files are considered to be part of the framework or part of the application, so there are a few possibilities.

1. If you also have the framework itself in your repository, it is ethically best to release only the files of your application under the (L)GPL and release the files belonging to the framework under their original (MIT) license.
2. If you don't (re-)distribute the entire Rails framework, but only a few files that get customized for every application (but are still considered part of the framework), you are probably fine with releasing the entire repository under (L)GPL, on account of the sublicense grant in the MIT license of the Rails framework. But only a lawyer can tell for sure if this interpretation of the licenses is correct.
3. If you don't (re-)distribute the Rails framework and those "stock" files (`boot.rb`, `application.rb`, etc.) are considered to be part of the application, then you are definitely fine with releasing the entire repository under (L)GPL.